# How do I stop text going below the image to its left?

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

OK, so I have an image and some text to its right.

When there is enough text, the text will start to move under the image and continue from there, for example:

```
[ IMAGE ] text text text text 
[ HERE! ] text text text text 
text text text text text text 
text text text text text text
```

Instead, I want it to look like this:

```
[ IMAGE ] text text text text 
[ HERE! ] text text text text 
          text text text text 
          text text text text 
          text text text text
```

How would I go about doing this? I'm sure there's a simple fix, maybe something to do with the image's display property, align properties or something.

Thank you!

Comment: As there was nothing broken, there was nothing to fix. There was just working CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple way of getting this effect, for example:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
div img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
div p {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8Rarq/

Comment: You are very welcome! Please remember to accept the answer.  All the best!

Comment: What about if there are multiple <p> tags below the image? They seem to not work the same way http://jsfiddle.net/8Rarq/2/

Comment: @AVeryDev   
I would put the <p> tags in a wrapper div and set the wrapper div to have overflow: auto See updated: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8Rarq/4 You may need to adjust margins on the nested elements depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

A container  for your text would be an easy solution.  Choose how much space you want your text to occupy and make a class in your css with a hidden border.  Here's an example of something I use:

```
.text-box{
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px; 
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I just tried the other solution from Marc and it worked perfectly, but thank you for taking the time to help out also though! This may help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure and expected result.

Do you *never* want the text to go below the image? In that case, the easiest approach would be to simply place the image in another parent than the text and float them next to each other. [Example here](http://www.codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/mzAqj).

Or, if you don't have or don't want those additional elements, give your `<p>` (or whatever is wrapping your text) an `overflow` value of `hidden`. [Example here](http://www.codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/FjiGA).

Lastly, if you want the text to float beneath the image but not right away, you could simply give your image a bottom margin to push the text down. [Example here](http://www.codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/nqLDH).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following CSS

```
img { float: left; }
p{ overflow: auto; }
```